# Can I make Windows XP remember my monitor when I start up with the monitor off/disconnected?

Tags: windows-xp, display, amd-radeon

I often start my computer with the monitor disconnected (really, set to display another PC via a KVM switch), and Windows always defaults to low-res display when this happens.

Is there any way to force Windows XP to remember my monitor configuration on reboot, so it doesn't have to probe my monitor on start up?

EDIT: I'm using an ATI HD4800 graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

It is an utterly ugly solution, but you could use a CLI tool like [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html), create a batch file around it, and have it run on startup to set the configuration manually - the command should be something like nircmd.exe setdisplay 1280 800 32

there's also a way to make a self contained command short cut - poke around the help file for that.

Comment: Thanks.  I've noticed that after a reboot with the monitor disconnected, I can't even change the display settings from the Display Properties--it only shows one display mode as available. Will this command work even in that case?

Comment: i have no idea. nearly all my systems are laptops, so switching display modes in that fashion dosen't seem to be an option. The alternative i've seen is registry editing, and that seems a little.. extreme.

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't work. It seems to be limited to the same resolutions shown in the Display Properties dialog.